# Unable to access S3 from EC2 Instance in Cloudformation -- A client error (301) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Moved Permanently

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, http-error, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to download a file from an S3 bucket to an instance through the userdata property of the instance. However, I get the error:

> A client error (301) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation:
>   Moved Permanently.

I use an IAM Role, Managed Policy, and Instance Profile to give the instance accessibility to the s3 bucket:

> ```
>     "Role": {
>         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
>         "Properties": {
>             "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
>                 "Statement": [
>                     {
>                         "Effect": "Allow",
>                         "Principal": {
>                             "Service": [
>                                 "ec2.amazonaws.com",
>                                 "s3.amazonaws.com"
>                             ]
>                         },
>                         "Action": [
>                             "sts:AssumeRole"
>                         ]
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
>             "Path": "/",
>             "ManagedPolicyArns": [
>                 {
>                     "Ref": "ManagedPolicy"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         "Metadata": {
>             "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
>                 "id": "069d4411-2718-400f-98dd-529bb95fd531"
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     "RolePolicy": {
>         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
>         "Properties": {
>             "PolicyName": "S3Download",
>             "PolicyDocument": {
>                 "Statement": [
>                     {
>                         "Action": [
>                             "s3:*"
>                         ],
>                         "Effect": "Allow",
>                         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
>             "Roles": [
>                 {
>                     "Ref": "Role"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         "Metadata": {
>             "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
>                 "id": "babd8869-948c-4b8a-958d-b1bff9d3063b"
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     "InstanceProfile": {
>         "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
>         "Properties": {
>             "Path": "/",
>             "Roles": [
>                 {
>                     "Ref": "Role"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         "Metadata": {
>             "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
>                 "id": "890c4df0-5d25-4f2c-b81e-05a8b8ab37c4"
>             }
>         }
>     },
> ```

And I attempt to download the file using this line in the userdata property:

> aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/login.keytab
>   destination_directory/

Any thoughts as to what is going wrong? I can download the file successfully if I make it public then use wget from the command line, but for some reason the bucket/file can't be found when using cp and the file isn't publicly accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Moved Permanently` normally indicates that you are being redirected to the location of the object. This is normally because the request is being sent to an endpoint that is in a **different region**.

Add a `--region` parameter where the region matches the bucket's region. For example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/login.keytab destination_directory/ --region ap-southeast-2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify `/root/.aws/credentials` file and add region like `region = ap-southeast-2`